# How to represent a mix of enum and oneof in protobuf

Tags: protocol-buffers

I am trying to create a protocol buffer message with fields that are either a message or one of a choice of some constant (like an enum). Something that is logically equivalent to:

```
message Error {
  oneof error_type {
    EMPTY_METHOD_NAME = 0
    ExecutionError execution_error = 1;
  }
  message ExecutionError {
    string value = 1;
  }
}
```

Essentially, I would like a field that can represent either an error type that is just a name with no fields, or an error type that has fields. How would I do this with protobuf3?

Answer (score 0):

See [Enumerations](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3#enum) in the [Language Guide (proto3)](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/proto3)

```
message Error {
  oneof error_type {
    Foo foo = 1;
    ExecutionError execution_error = 2;
  }
  enum Foo {
    X = 0;
    Y = 1;
    Z = 2;
  }
  message ExecutionError {
    string value = 1;
  }
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no way to have `error_type` value be either `X` or `executionError{value=some_string}`, not `foo{X}`?